# AngularJS Routing not working. Getting blank output

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-route

I am not sure why the routing isnt working. View1.html consists of a simple web page and the same goes with view2.html. Both view1.html and view2.html are in a folder called partials and "angular-route.js" and "angular-route.min.js" are in a folder called node_modules in home folder. I am using ubuntu 14.04.

```
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>


<script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

    demoApp.config( function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController' ,
                templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html' //
            })
            .when('/view2',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController' ,
                templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' })
    })

    demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope)
        {


$scope.customers = [{name:'nihal',city:'hyderabad'},{name:'nihal',city:'mumbai'}, {name:'john',city:'bangalore'}]
        $scope.addCustomer = function() {
            $scope.customers.push({name: newCustomer.name , city: newCustomer.city })
        }
    })


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same issue here. However my page shows view2 at initial state. Look for an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax in routes, comma is missing after controller property.

Comment: Thank you. There was a syntax error. I corrected it. 
Still not working .

Comment: have you figure out what the problem is? I am having exact issue while following Dan's 60mins angular tutorial